# 'Translation' dilemma

Tags: programming-languages, translation

I'm trying to build a website that reads Icelandic texts written in a particular font which are then rendered in a different character encoding (ascii/uc) and cached before finally being displayed. What language is best suited for the job? Python or PHP? Or anything else? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you mean "character encoding," not "font."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has been used to create the [Natural Language Processing Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/), which may be useful for you. PHP is generally conceded to be behind the curve on leaving 8-bit text behind, although it's catching up in current versions.